# How can I write a better 'tree' (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie in coding and I got an assignement:

*You ask the user to enter a random number, which expresses the size of the 'Christmas tree'. The trunk is not included in the size of the tree.*
*Example:
size = 5
(5 is the 'input number', that the user has enetered.)*
*Then in the terminal you get this:*
[image]

I think I almost finished this, but I just need some more help.

So, here's what I' ve done so far:

```
def print_spruce(n):
   for i in range(1, n+1, 2): 
          print (" " *(n-i) + "X"*(2*i-1))
          print (" " * (n-1) + "X")
n = int(input("Write the size of the spruce:"))
print_spruce(n+1)
```

Terminal:

[image]

Can someone give me a tip/advice/anything/specific help to finish this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A word of advice for new programmers: **there is no task so small that you cannot put it into its own method**. If you had written `def print_spruce(n): print_branches(n) print_trunk(n)` and then written implementations for `print_branches` and `print_trunk`, you would have automatically eliminated one of your bugs, and made the other one easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you draw the trunk every loop, by simply moving the trunk drawing code out of the for loop it is only drawn once in the end as it should. Also, you should use steps of 1 rather than steps of 2 in your for loop and there is no use for n+1 when calling `print_spruce()`.

Try this:

```
def print_spruce(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print (" " *(n-i) + "X"*(2*i-1))
    print (" " * (n-1) + "X")
n = int(input("Write the size of the spruce:"))
print_spruce(n)
```

Comment: It's better than  mine, but two lines are missing (the one which with 3Xs and the one with  7Xs). prtscr: https://imgur.com/a/Ku18IwM

Comment: @Felix579 This is because you use steps of 2 in your for loop when actually you should use steps of 1, also there is no need for n+1.

Comment: I followed your advice and now everything is OK. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix579 Feel free to accept my answer for reputation sake.